# When and how create packages in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Have something that is making me sleep lately: How and when use packages?

### My case:

- I want to create a Books package (crud)
- I want to create an user/authenticator package (crud + login)

### My doubt:

- Book belongsTo User, so... how to do that?
- In what file I put this relationship?
- If user is not a package and it's a normal controller/model in my "app" how to set this relationship?
- This "relationship file" exists in theses packages or outside (in the my "app")

---

It's not just a doubt about implementation, **it's about concept too**.

If you need more information, tell me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not the best to go into Laravel packages much, but the relationship would be held within a model (so you could say something like `$Book->getUser()` or `$User->getBooks()` assuming it is a one-to-many relationship).

Answer (score 2):

#### When to create a package?

When you understand that the code you are creating will, probably, be needed in some other application or to a different developer. That's basically how Open Source works, I create a package, you use it in your application. Of course there are other reasons, like the DRY (don't repeat yourself), but in this case they might be secondary.

So if you think your Books Service will be needed in a different app, so yes, why not creating a package for it?

A user/authenticator is surely something we all need in our apps, maybe not all, but many of them, so, again, yes, create a [Composer Package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) for it.

#### Book belongsTo User, so... how to do that?

This is how you represent this relationship:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Book');      
    }

}
```

#### If user is not a package and it's a normal controller/model in my "app" how to set this relationship?

This is not a package, but in a package you would just refer to the User model in the package namespace:

```
use MyPackage\Models\User;
```

#### This "relationship file" exists in theses packages or outside (in the my "app")

The "file" itself is your model file and it is present in your package, but since you need to request the package in your composer.json file, that file will be present in the vendor folder.

Having a relationship in a model and this model in a package, if you are "importing" the package model, this model also exists in your application.

And you put this class in your `models` folder in your `User.php` file, if you are using Laravel 4.x.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Antonio, helped a lot! So I need to "use the other package (in the header of my file)... ok. And I also need to put the package I'll be using in my composer.json, right? After all, the books packet depends on the user.